# Reload data without refresh a component when navigate to another route

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the component B that contains a post method which insert new data and also navigates to the component A directly ,this one contains a get method which displays the inserted data.

Now I would like to know how I can have the new data without refreshing the page knowing that I succeeded but I have to put navigation end on the ngOnInit and the constructor.

```
constructor(private auth: FirstAksamProspectService, private router: Router) {

this.router.events.subscribe((router) => {
  if (router instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    this.getlistAffectaion_employe();
  }
});
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

this.router.events.subscribe((router) => {
  if (router instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    this.getlistAffectaion_employe();
  }
});

this.getlistAffectaion_employe();


}
```

Is there another way to do it?

thank you for your help

Comment: is this component A or B ?

Comment: this is component A

Comment: you can google "Sharing data between components in Angular." there is several ways to do what you want ... you can use service that holds your shared data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a service that would hold a BehaviorSubject and an observable:

`private yourSubject: BehaviorSubject<void> = new BehaviorSubject<void>(); public yourObservable: Observable<void> = this.yourSubject.asObservable();`

When you post you have to trigger a `next()` on the BehaviorSubject through a public method in your Service and then in your component A, in the ngOnInit you subscribe to `yourObservable`. In the subscribe you can then call `this.getlistAffectaion_employe();`